# PHP file get content without upload

Tags: php

I want the user to submit an XML file and i want to parse the file using PHP.
Is it possible to get file contents without uploading it on server using PHP?

Thanks.

Comment: No it is not possible.

Comment: Why don't you want to upload the file and then process it? What is the problem?

Comment: so you want to check if its valid XML ?? you can use html5 to get the contents and use the internal DOM parser of the browser ... 
[DOM Parser](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_parser.asp) [HTML5 to read content](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. PHP runs on the server, so the data to be processed must be sent to the server for that to be possible.

JavaScript, on the other hand, runs in the client's browser. Using JavaScript you could process a file selected by the user without sending it to a server first, for instance if you want to preprocess it before sending it to the server.